# Bitte nicht öffnen! Bissig!

Tags: translation

I came across the book "Bitte nicht öffnen! Bissig!" by Charlotte Habersack.

I understand that the title is "Please do not open!", but I don't understand the "Bissig!" part. A German to English dictionary translates bissig as vicious, but this doesn't make sense with the title.

Can anyone explain the meaning of bissig in the context of this title?

Would bissig in this context be similar to Achtung?

Comment: A literal translation would be "bitey"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a warning associated with dogs guarding property, that something might snap at you if you ignore the warning. At the same time, it is also used metaphorically for statements/words that might hurt or are agressive.

See the [Duden entry for "bissig"](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bissig). As I read it, the book title plays with both meanings. But perhaps I overinterpreted that, because that seems to be part of a series, and the other titles contain the warnings "Schleimig"(Slimy) and "Feurig"(Hot).